# Removing the continuous end loop for PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I have a script for pinging IP addresses. The script is well designed so I thought of using it in my script as one of the functions. However, the problem with the script is that it has a never ending loop for pinging which I do not want. I am not able to figure out where the changes have to be made.

```
      Function Ping-Host
      {
    #Parameter Definition
     Param
(
[Parameter(position = 0)] $Hosts,
[Parameter] $ToCsv
)
    #Funtion to make space so that formatting looks good
    Function Make-Space($l,$Maximum)
    {
    $space =""
    $s = [int]($Maximum - $l) + 1
    1..$s | %{$space+=" "}

    return [String]$space
    }
#Array Variable to store length of all hostnames
$LengthArray = @() 
$Hosts | %{$LengthArray += $_.length}

#Find Maximum length of hostname to adjust column witdth accordingly
$Maximum = ($LengthArray | Measure-object -Maximum).maximum
$Count = $hosts.Count

#Initializing Array objects 
$Success = New-Object int[] $Count
$Failure = New-Object int[] $Count
$Total = New-Object int[] $Count
cls
#Running a never ending loop
while($true){

$i = 0 #Index number of the host stored in the array
$out = "| HOST$(Make-Space 4 $Maximum)| STATUS | SUCCESS  | FAILURE  | ATTEMPTS  |" 
$Firstline=""
1..$out.length|%{$firstline+="_"}

#output the Header Row on the screen
Write-Host $Firstline 
Write-host $out -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Black

$Hosts|%{
$total[$i]++
If(Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 -Quiet -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
{
$success[$i]+=1
#Percent calclated on basis of number of attempts made
$SuccessPercent = $("{0:N2}" -f (($success[$i]/$total[$i])*100))
$FailurePercent = $("{0:N2}" -f (($Failure[$i]/$total[$i])*100))

#Print status UP in GREEN if above condition is met
Write-Host "| $_$(Make-Space $_.Length $Maximum)| UP$(Make-Space 2 4)  | $SuccessPercent`%$(Make-Space ([string]$SuccessPercent).length 6) | $FailurePercent`%$(Make-Space ([string]$FailurePercent).length 6) | $($Total[$i])$(Make-Space ([string]$Total[$i]).length 9)|" -BackgroundColor Green
}
else
{
$Failure[$i]+=1

#Percent calclated on basis of number of attempts made
$SuccessPercent = $("{0:N2}" -f (($success[$i]/$total[$i])*100))
 $FailurePercent = $("{0:N2}" -f (($Failure[$i]/$total[$i])*100))

#Print status DOWN in RED if above condition is met
Write-Host "| $_$(Make-Space $_.Length $Maximum)| DOWN$(Make-Space 4 4)  | $SuccessPercent`%$(Make-Space ([string]$SuccessPercent).length 6) | $FailurePercent`%$(Make-Space ([string]$FailurePercent).length 6) | $($Total[$i])$(Make-Space ([string]$Total[$i]).length 9)|" -BackgroundColor Red
}
$i++

}

#Pause the loop for few seconds so that output 
#stays on screen for a while and doesn't refreshes

Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
cls
}
}

 Ping-Host -Hosts 10.50.5.16,10.50.5.33
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `while ($true) {` and corresponding `}`. Then each time you call Ping-Host, the function will ping only once.

Comment: Thanks paul. What if I want to ping for 10 times

Comment: Paul, I got the answer. Thank you very much

Comment: "#Running a never ending loop" is a bit misleading now :)

Answer (score 0):

With help of Paul and some searching in google, came up with an solution.

Changes made
1) as paul indicated remove while($true){} loop
2) adding do while

```
     Function Ping-Host
  {
#Parameter Definition
Param
(
[Parameter(position = 0)] $Hosts,
[Parameter] $ToCsv
)
    #Funtion to make space so that formatting looks good
    Function Make-Space($l,$Maximum)
    {
    $space =""
    $s = [int]($Maximum - $l) + 1
    1..$s | %{$space+=" "}

    return [String]$space
    }
#Array Variable to store length of all hostnames
$LengthArray = @() 
$Hosts | %{$LengthArray += $_.length}

#Find Maximum length of hostname to adjust column witdth accordingly
$Maximum = ($LengthArray | Measure-object -Maximum).maximum
$Count = $hosts.Count

#Initializing Array objects 
$Success = New-Object int[] $Count
$Failure = New-Object int[] $Count
$Total = New-Object int[] $Count
cls
#Running a never ending loop
DO

  {$j++
$i = 0 #Index number of the host stored in the array
$out = "| HOST$(Make-Space 4 $Maximum)| STATUS | SUCCESS  | FAILURE  | ATTEMPTS  |" 
$Firstline=""
1..$out.length|%{$firstline+="_"}

#output the Header Row on the screen
Write-Host $Firstline 
Write-host $out -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Black

$Hosts|%{
$total[$i]++
If(Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 -Quiet -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
{
$success[$i]+=1
#Percent calclated on basis of number of attempts made
$SuccessPercent = $("{0:N2}" -f (($success[$i]/$total[$i])*100))
$FailurePercent = $("{0:N2}" -f (($Failure[$i]/$total[$i])*100))

#Print status UP in GREEN if above condition is met
Write-Host "| $_$(Make-Space $_.Length $Maximum)| UP$(Make-Space 2 4)  | $SuccessPercent`%$(Make-Space ([string]$SuccessPercent).length 6) | $FailurePercent`%$(Make-Space ([string]$FailurePercent).length 6) | $($Total[$i])$(Make-Space ([string]$Total[$i]).length 9)|" -BackgroundColor Green
}
else
{
$Failure[$i]+=1

#Percent calclated on basis of number of attempts made
$SuccessPercent = $("{0:N2}" -f (($success[$i]/$total[$i])*100))
 $FailurePercent = $("{0:N2}" -f (($Failure[$i]/$total[$i])*100))

#Print status DOWN in RED if above condition is met
Write-Host "| $_$(Make-Space $_.Length $Maximum)| DOWN$(Make-Space 4 4)  | $SuccessPercent`%$(Make-Space ([string]$SuccessPercent).length 6) | $FailurePercent`%$(Make-Space ([string]$FailurePercent).length 6) | $($Total[$i])$(Make-Space ([string]$Total[$i]).length 9)|" -BackgroundColor Red
}
$i++

}

#Pause the loop for few seconds so that output 
#stays on screen for a while and doesn't refreshes

Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
cls

  }while($j -ne 10 )

}
   Ping-Host -Hosts 10.50.5.16,10.50.5.33
```

This will ping 10 times

Comment: You might update your comment too. "`#Running a never ending loop`" is a bit misleading now :)